# Only allow file download with active session

Tags: php, file, session, server

Is it possible to set preferences of files/directorys on my server to not downloadable, but if the user has a session, he has acces to the files and can download them.

I know that i can disable the "download button" with `$_SESSION`, for example:

```
$downloadbutton = "<a href='abc.jpg'>Download</a>";
if($_SESSION["xy"] == "abc"){
    echo $downloadbutton
}
```

**But** it is possible to acces the file by `www.url.com/directpath/abc.jpg`

So how is it possible to secure the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more control over the download you can use the following function:

```
function makeDownload($file, $dir, $type) {

header("Content-Type: $type");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");

readfile($dir.$file);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict a direct access by checking `PHPSESSID` cookie in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} PHPSESSID=[^;]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Better example with SetEnv:

```
SetenvIf Cookie PHPSESSID=[^;] permit
Allow from env=permit
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure download access you should never actually serve the files from their original URL, always use a file proxy. That way the user never sees where the file comes from and can only use your proxy script, where you have control over whether it can be served.

If you look around, there are tons of scripts that have already been written specifically. You can find one of them [here](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download) and add your session verification to it.

Comment: Thanks, i think i will combine this method with some other methods :)